# Why does the output of my print function show paragraphs and commas?

Tags: python-2.7, function, printing

Hello dear Stackoverflow community,
I'm a Python newbie using Pycharm and encountered one seemingly small issue:
**When I run this code**

```
def do_math(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

math1 = do_math(5, 7)
math2 = do_math(11, 34)

print("The first sum is", math1, "and the second sum is", math2)

print("hello world")
```

**I get this**

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 /Users/hallkevi/PycharmProjects/FirstProgram/main.py
>
> ('The first sum is', 12, 'and the second sum is', 45)
> hello world
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Why do I get the first print output showed in brackets and commas?

Comment: hi @kevin-haller, you cannot use a function to assign variable like you are doing.

Comment: use `pep-8` to format your code and also make sure you do a `ctrl+k`with the code you are putting on SO

Comment: You can put your code in code blocks thus making your question much more presentable. Also, use more paragraphs when and as needed to improve the legibility of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Cause that's the way `print` function works. You're basically printing out 4 variables in one print statement.

Try that for example.

```
print('foo', 'bar')
print('foo' + 'bar')
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for your help.

So how do I implement the variables 'math1' and 'math2' correctly in the print function, that I get the output: 

`The first sum is 12 and the second sum is 45` 

without the brackets and commas?

Comment: No worries man. You can do it in several ways, but the most pythonic is to use `format()` on a string: `print('The first sum is {first} and the second sum is {second}'.format(first=math1, second=math2))`

Comment: Or like that: `print(' '.join(['The first sum is', math1, 'and the second sum is', math2]))`

Comment: The most inefficient way is this one: `print('The first sum is ' + math1 + ' and the second sum is ' + math2)`